# Why is "zur Schule" inside the verbal bracket here?

Tags: grammar-identification, subordinate-clause, compound, position

> Manchmal, wenn er mit diesem lächerlichen Haarschnitt partout nicht *hatte **zur Schule** gehen wollen*, hatte er es geschafft, dass sein Haar rasch nachwuchs…

I'm trying to learn German and I recently picked up reading; as a result I get exposed to a lot of new vocabulary.

I'm used that at the end of a clause (excluding Nachfeld) there're only verbs.
Could it be that *zur Schule* forms a pair with *gehen*, the kind that acts like a separable verb, and *that's* why, to my surprise, there is something else than verbs at the end of this clause?

Comment: "something else than a verb at the end of this clause" - what is it?

Comment: the verbal brackets (im pretty sure - but correct me if im wrong) in this clause my question is relevant to are "wenn" - the opening one, and "hatte zur Schule gehen wollen" - the closing one. I am trying to figure out why is zur Schule, a prepositional phrase part of a verbal bracket, as i am used to only see verbs inside them (at least in the closing ones).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sentence shows the *Sonderregel* of the ordering of infinitive verbs.
When the second infinitive verb is reigned by a modal verb, in your case *wollen*, the auxiliary *haben* is placed directly to the left of the two:
(Duden Grammar Nr.684)

> , was sie nicht *hatte machen wollen*.

Duden Grammar Nr 686 tells us that if the *Sonderregel* is used, a constituent that is closely connected to the infinitive main verb can be pushed between *haben* and infinitive main verb:

> , was sie nicht hatte in Anspruch nehmen müssen.
> , was sie nicht in Anspruch hatte nehmen müssen.

> , weshalb sie nicht hatte zur Schule gehen wollen.
> , weshalb sie nicht zur Schule hatte gehen wollen.

It does not change any meaning.

---

*Wenn* is used as a temporal subjunction, like English "when".

Comment: fantastic.... great job, glad i waited and didn't assume stuff. this must be it!

Answer (score 0):

I have also found the answer myself now encouraged by your answer in an English source:

*Hammer's German Grammar and Usage 7th edition*
19.1.3b(v) and
19.7.2 of which does also mention that "these phrases" are part of the verbal bracket (besides what you mentioned).

Feels bad when I could've found the answer myself in a book I own but for some reason I didn't imagine I could find the answer at the section of "verb order in the final position".

Comment: In Duden it is a very short paragraph of a few sentences too, so one can easily overlook it.